# Plotting an infinite series

Tags: plotting, series-expansion

I need to plot Maclaurin Series for some functions. I tried to define the series like:

```
series1 = Series[Exp[x], {x, 0, 6}]
```

and tried to plot it

```
Plot[series1, {x, 0, 5}]
```

and also use `Normal` function, like:

```
Plot[Normal[series1], {x, 0, 5}]
```

but unfortunately none of the above worked. How can I do it?

Comment: I did series1 = Normal[Series[Exp[x], {x, 0, 6}]] and after Plot[series1, {x, 0, 5}] and worked

Comment: try also `Plot[Evaluate@Normal[series1], {x, 0, 5}]`

Answer (score 2):

```
Plot[Evaluate @ Normal[series1], {x, 0, 5}]
```

[image]