# Plotting a Maclaurin series

Tags: plotting, series-expansion

Can anyone plot the degree-8 Maclaurin polynomial for the function $(x+1)/((x^2)-9)$ and function $(x+1)/((x^2)-9)$ on the same plot.

Please help, I've tried everything I could think of.

Comment: Possible duplicates:  [(7559)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7559), [(130464)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/130464), [(158080)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/158080), [(160684)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/160684)

Answer (score 6):

The problem is probably that `Series` returns a `SeriesData` object. It must be converted to a polynomial with `Normal` before it can be plotted.

```
f = (x + 1)/((x^2) - 9);
p = Normal[Series[f, {x, 0, 8}]]
Plot[{f, p}, {x, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: Plotting over a wider range will highlight the differences.

`Plot[{f, p}, {x, -4, 4},
 PlotRange -> {-3, 3},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{"function", "polynomial"}, {.7, .7}]]`